# Bigquery.client() thorws Oauth connection time out error

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to connect bigquery via Google. I have service account for my project and while trying to access query I am getting time out error.

> Error : connection to oauth2.googleapis.com time out

**Code snippet:**

```
from google.cloud import Bigquery
client =bigquery.Client()

client.query("")
```